# Statically set the speed of a CPU fan

Tags: dc, fan, 12v

I have two types of DC 12V CPU fans, type [AFC0612DE](http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/DELTA%20PRODUCTS%20CORPORATION/AFC0612DE-AF00.pdf) (Delta Electronics) and [TA350DC](http://www.nidecamerica.com/fanpdfs/ta350dc.pdf) (Nidec).

Both types have PWM pins for speed control. I however do not have a controller.

I would like to set the speed of these fans to something other than the max speed while not having to build a PWM controller to control the speed.

My input power comes from a 220VAC - 12VDC ~2A transformer.

I have tried putting a 450 ohm resistor before the fan, this makes the fans not start at all.

Having two fans in the circuit either serially or in parallell also makes the fans not start at all.

---

My concern is the noise from the fans when they run at maximum speed, I could have two fans if that would work, only if they don't run at maximum speed.

Is it possible to modify any of the static input parameters to change the fan speed? I have some old VCR, PC parts that might contain the missing things, so tell me what I need and I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Why don't you provide a proper link to the fans instead of expecting folk to retype what you have written into their browsers. Common courtesy I'm talking about. You might also provide a link for the fan power circuit so folk can try and work-out why two fans in parallel don't work. Will two fans at half speed reduce noise?

Comment: @Andyaka I added product links, the Delta Electronics fan might contain that information. I'm an electronicx newcomer myself so it's hard to tell. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Fans in parallel with a 2A(DC) power supply and they won't start? Something fundamentally wrong then. You didn't mix up positive and negative terminals?

Comment: Please upload a circuit diagram and a picture of your set up.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to build a simple [pwm controller](http://www.bit-tech.net/modding/2001/12/03/pwm_fan_controller/1)?

Comment: Unless you can modify the circuit inside the fan, or unless it's immediately low-pass filtering the PWM to an analog level, you are going to have to build a simple PWM generator, either with an analog circuit or with a cheap miniature microcontroller.

Comment: What you're asking for is basically how to run a car without fuel. You can't. PWM is very simple to create. The 555 chip can do a nice job.

Answer (score 2):

I added fans to the backs of my computer monitors to allow them to run cooler and hopefully extend their lifespan. I used computer CPU fans similar to yours that have the 4 wire connections including the PWM input. To lower the noise and be able to control the fan speed I built a simple little box that takes in 12V from a AC->DC wall type power module and then outputs that to four fan connectors on the back of the box. Internally I designed a very simple circuit that runs off 12V and uses two 555 timer chips to produce a 22KHz requency waveform and then uses a pot on the second 555 timer chip to create a PWM signal to drive the four fans.

I'll post a picture of the schematic later so you could use the same design if you wish.